# Nothing returned from taxonomy_term_load function

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

The --very normal-- taxonomy_term_load() doesn't seem to be able to load entities within a custom menu callback. Yet I can access a profile entity, load fields, and get the field tids, but I get nothing from the taxonomy load function!

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user/account-convert'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Page',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_page() {
  global $user;
  $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user, 'my_profile_type');
  // Sanity check tid return. Success.
  echo $profile->field_profile_myfield[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
  // Term name returns nothing. The object just won't load.
  echo taxonomy_term_load($profile->field_profile_myfield[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'])->name;
}
```

This makes absolutely no sense.

I have even sanity checked outputting hard coded tid's like `echo taxonomy_term_load(1708)` after 100% confirming it's a valid tid value.

Additionally I followed the function tree up and tried calling `taxonomy_term_load_multiple`
 directly, and `entity_load` directly. All give me nothing.

Furthermore I can confirm the function is valid and available at that point with `function_exists`, and the lack of undefined function errors.

Comment: Not sure this is related, but your menu item is missing one/both of `access callback` and `access arguments` (at least one is required in [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)). Other than that I can't reproduce the problem...`taxonomy_term_load()` works perfectly for me when I use it in a page callback

Comment: I left out my `access callback` function for code example clarity. Guess if this works for you, I need to create a separate module with just this and build up from there.

Comment: Super weird. Just used a `db_query` even though it felt wrong.

Comment: BTW: The problem was a taxonomy_access problem not allowing me to load the entity for the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, this is a [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) issue.

See [`taxonomy_access_query_term_access_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!taxonomy_access!taxonomy_access.module/function/taxonomy_access_query_term_access_alter/7).

(For the rest of the Internet, I only know this is the issue because Josh and I are working on the same codebase and I ran into the exact same issue in a completely different context.)

Comment: It happens with [Tac Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) too

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
function get_tag_name($tid) {
    $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't');
    $query
            ->condition('t.tid', $tid, '=')
            ->fields('t', array('tid', 'name'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        return $row->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with a select query solution, but the point was how to *avoid* that. BTW: The problem was a taxonomy_access problem not allowing loading the entity.